# How to download all extractors along with the endpoints for RESTful request?

Tags: import.io

I've been using import.io to extract lots of data from hundreds of web pages. I've already created extractors for those URLs and still adding more.

I've designed an automated process that sends an HTTP request to the import.io RESTful API for all extractors recursively.

Every time I create a new extractor, I perform some manual task to insert the endpoint of the newly created extractor into my database. This approach is very time consuming and may be error prone since there is a chance of copy/paste error.

Although import.io maintains the list of my data, I'd love to download all the extractors along with their endpoints for RESTful request so that the data can be stored into my database.

Is there a way to download or extract all of my data into excel format or some other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there is no way to Bulk download API endpoints for all your extractors I'm afraid.

It is possible to get the GUIDs of you connectors using this method.

http://api.docs.import.io/legacy/#ConnectorMethods  "search connectors"

You could write a small script in python for example to parse this to get the GUIDs.

Potentially you could add this to your automated process.

Comment: Thanks Alex !

I was able to get the list of my extractors as per your suggestion. But I'd like to suggest import.io to include the feature to bulk download API endpoints through the app.

Comment: Its a good idea! I'm going to pass this on to the import.io product team :)